# How to download all files from that are linked within a text?

Tags: windows, file-download

I would like to download all .mp3 files that are linked in a .XML file such as this one: http://blog.iso50.com/audio/pl17/playlist-wordtube.xml

Is there a tool available for it? 
Thank you
Sarah

Comment: Sarah - When I go to this page I get a parse error.  You could however use a tool such as wget to grab all of the files if the page was actually working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Firefox addon : [DownThemAll!!](http://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/downthemall/)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have access to the two tools, `wget` and `Perl`, get the file, `playlist-wordtube.xml` with the command:

```
$ wget http://blog.iso50.com/audio/pl17/playlist-wordtube.xml
```

Now, you can see the files that are to be downloaded from the `playlist-wordtube.xml` file with the following Perl script:

```
$ perl -e 'while (<>) {if (/mp3<\/location>/) {s/^[^<]+<location>(.*)<\/location>/$1/; print;}}' < playlist-wordtube.xml | head
http://blog.iso50.com/audio/pl17/01-Awake.mp3
http://blog.iso50.com/audio/pl17/02-GardensVilla-Bullet-Train.mp3
http://blog.iso50.com/audio/pl17/03-Antiphon.mp3
http://blog.iso50.com/audio/pl17/04AtomsForPeace-Dropped.mp3
http://blog.iso50.com/audio/pl17/05Veaquis1.mp3
http://blog.iso50.com/audio/pl17/06Jade1.mp3
http://blog.iso50.com/audio/pl17/07JonHopkins.mp3
http://blog.iso50.com/audio/pl17/08MadmenLove.mp3
http://blog.iso50.com/audio/pl17/09Jet1.mp3
http://blog.iso50.com/audio/pl17/10Spiral.mp3
```

Changing the `print` to `wget` in the above `perl` script, we have an answer to your question:

```
$ perl -e 'while (<>) {if (/mp3<\/location>/) {s/^[^<]+<location>(.*)<\/location>/$1/; `wget $_`;}}' < playlist-wordtube.xml
[LOTS OF INTERNET FILE TRANSFER HANDSHAKING MESSAGES]
$ ls -1 | head
01-Awake.mp3
02-GardensVilla-Bullet-Train.mp3
03-Antiphon.mp3
04AtomsForPeace-Dropped.mp3
05Veaquis1.mp3
06Jade1.mp3
07JonHopkins.mp3
08MadmenLove.mp3
09Jet1.mp3
10Spiral.mp3
```

Comment: Good answer if he weren't using windows

Comment: I read that Windows caveat. There are `Windows` equivalents, 1st being `cygwin` with `wget` and `perl` nicely packaged up.  At one time a  free `Windows` `UNIX` command line set of tools sanctioned by Microsoft was also available.  A quick Google search yields, `http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/wget.htm`. From the README files at CPAN, there's at least one `Windows` `Perl`.  `Cygwin` may be installed for free from here, http://cygwin.com/install.html, and using the `html` installation option, it can be installed by non-administers from behind firewalls.  The solution is now complete.